Not finding module 'dateutil', but it is installed. No module named 'dateutil' No module named 'dateutil'
I had this error on my notebook. I reinstalled dateutil in many different ways. I tried restarting jupyter notebook and now it doesn't open  giving same error
No module named 'dateutil'
I have tried :
sudo pip install python-dateutil
pip3 install python-dateutil
pip install --force-reinstall 
pip install --force-reinstall --update

I usually get this output:
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages (2.9.0.post0)

No matter how many times I uninstall and reinstall the problem persists. I didn't have this issue a few hours ago. I downgraded and re upgraded numpy because I wanted to use statsmodels but gave up.

You may have installed the package in your terminal, but have you checked that the active environment for your Jupyter notebook is the same as the terminal you've installed the package with? This is why virtual environments are encouraged. Are you using anaconda to open your jupyter notebook?

Why is "no module named 'dateutil'" in the title twice?

I don't use a virtual environment atm. I use anaconda but I open jupyter from terminal

what does conda list show

You use an environment then if you are using Anaconda. Please read the 'Getting Started' documentation they provide. Also learn how to connect an an ipykernel to an environment from the top two answers here. Bcause your actively chose Anaconda/conda as your primary package manager you should be using it for all package managenent steps, only resorting to pip for things that do not have conda recipes. Check what the active kernel sees by running %conda list in your running Jupyter Notebook.

 Based on here and the use of the magic install command, you may want to try running inside your notebook, %conda install conda-forge::python-dateutil. Then restart the kernel and try the import.

You can try installing it from inside Jupyter.
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} dateutil
import dateutil

From: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/

For those interested, a more convenient magic version of that was introduced in 2019.  The magic %conda install makes sure it installs to the environment where the kernel is running. It would just be %conda install conda-forge::python-dateutil -y with the last part coming from the link I referenced in my comment to the original post. See more about the modern %conda install command here.

I fixed it by creating a new environment and reinstalling jupyter in the environment.
